# How to predict something along with dates in python?

Tags: python-3.x, time-series

I have time series data , the two columns are traffic density and date. I wish to predict the density for next 7 days.

I am using arime time series forecasting.  I am able to forecast density  but I want to forecast density with time. How can it be done?

Comment: use RNN for timeseries

Comment: too broad for SO.

Comment: I have flagged this question to be closed because it is too vague for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

GO with RNN(LSTM) or [FBProphet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html)

Here's a good piece of work for FBProphet:
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-start-of-time-series-forecasting-with-a-practical-example-using-fb-prophet-31c4447a2274

Here's a good piece of work for LSTM:
https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

---

However you can also look into ARIMA Variants.